# Run GUI program on remote machine via python subprocess ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, x11, python, x-server

Running Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 19.10, Python 3.7.5, `python3-xlib==0.15` and `pyautogui==0.9.50`. Everything is run as the default `ubuntu` user.

I'm trying to have `Machine A` send an ssh command to `Machine B` to run a GUI program and do some processing. I'm getting some `XAUTHORITY` errors.

Note: I don't want to see the GUI on `Machine A`s monitor - but the app running on `Machine B` needs a GUI.

So on `Machine A` I run:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'ubuntu@ip_of_machine_B', 'python3', '/path/to/my_script.py'])
```

On `Machine B`, `my_script.py` executes

```
subprocess.call(['python3', '/path/to/gui_script.py'])
```

Finally, `gui_script.py` attempts to

```
import os
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
os.environ['XAUTHORITY'] = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
import subprocess
import pyautogui


subprocess.Popen(['the_gui_app'])
# Do stuff with pyautogui and the app.
```

Unfortunately, `gui_script.py` is throwing the following

```
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": No protocol specified.
```

I also tried setting the environment in the `subprocess` call in `my_script.py` via

```
my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
my_env['XAUTHORITY'] = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
subprocess.call(['python3', '/path/to/gui_script.py'], env=my_env)
```

But that also failed.

My best guess is I need to change some setting somewhere on `Machine B` prior to running the workflow (ie, a one-time edit to `xauth`)? This is a closed system so security isn't an issue!

Comment: What is a RPi4s? Have you tried without the python. I know python, and I managed to filter it all out (it is not relevant). Any one not knowing python, will be confused by it. They may be the person that will be able to help. What is the simplest thing that has the problem?

Comment: May I suggest `ssh  ubuntu@ip_of_machine_B DISPLAY=:0 xmessage hello`. This may be the simplest thing that does not work. **Test it**.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I didn't boil it down to essentials because I don't know what the essentials are :). But I found the answer...`DISPLAY` was set to `:1`. I assumed that it would be `:0` from all the examples I googled...so I changed the environment setting to be `:1` and it worked. Good for `unix` novices though...I had no idea it could be set to something else. I feel silly now...

Comment: Not sure if I should answer the question for other unix newcomers or just vote to close it.